# How to change the font size of yticklabels in HeatMap MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, font-size, heatmap, figure

I am trying to generate a heatmap in MATLAB but unable to change the font size of the yticklabels. I am unable to find a function through which I can set the font-size of the whole object.

I tried to set font size of the whole figure using:

```
set(gca, 'fontsize', 18)
```

However, this is also not working. Following is the code and the generated figure.

```
df = randi(10,5,20);

labely = {'Room-1', 'Room-2', 'Room-3', 'Room-4', 'Room-5'};
HMobj = HeatMap(df, 'RowLabels', labely, 'Colormap', 'redbluecmap');

HMobj.addXLabel('Time of Day', 'FontSize', 18);
```

[image]

Comment: `HeatMap` is part of the **Bioinformatics Toolbox**, not to be confused with the new `heatmap` function in 2017a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no simple and straightforward way to do that. But it's not so complicated.

First, make all figure handles visible, so you can access all properties:

```
set(0,'ShowHiddenHandles','on')
```

Next, get the handle to the axes of the heat map:

```
h = findobj('Tag','HeatMapAxes');
```

Now, you can change what you want:

```
h.YAxis.FontSize = 18

% or  if you want to set the font size of all text in the figure:
set(findall(h,'Type','Text'),'FontSize',18)
```

[image]

Comment: So, they don't have any direct property name to do that?

Comment: Not for the axes tick labels, only for the labels, as you already did. You may want to try working with [`heatmap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/heatmap.html?s_tid=doc_ta) (if you have version 2017a) which seems to be more tweakable.

Comment: Okay! Thanks for the help.